# Get all form elements value to be attached for ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have an object that is inside of a form.

His value is assigned to an ajax call like this

```
var $$ = $(this);
if (typeof settings.data == 'string') {
   data = settings.data + '&' + this.name + '=' + $$.val();
 } else if (typeof settings.data == 'object') {
data = settings.data;
    data[this.name] = $$.val();
 }
```

I want to get the parent form of this element, and to loop through all inputs and add that too to the data to be used on an Ajax call.

I want the input name to be the key for the data array.

Probably something like:

```
var form = $$.parents('form:first');
```

and next thing to loop through the inputs and attach to data.

How to do that using jQuery?

Comment: not an answer but, `this.value` is better than `$$.val()`. that is if `$$ == $(this)`

Comment: Please tell *what* you are trying to do, not *how* you are trying to to it.

Comment: I want to post all form inputs to an ajax call. I have to get the input values in the data variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're reinventing the wheel here, there's already a [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method specifically for this, like this:

```
var data = $(this).closest("form").serialize();
```

Or if you want an object representation you can loop through/add to, you can use [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) then manipulate it before passing it as the data option. It's unclear *exactly* what you're after, but it *sounds* like you just want to pass the entire form as the data argument to [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [a short-hand version](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/), in which case [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see.use jQuery 'Form' plugin?
http://www.google.com.au/search?q=jquery+form+plugin&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

It will do all the work for you, and will work even for file uploadas (by creating hidden iframe on the fly and submitting it). IT also can use JSON and or XML format. PRetty handy one.

See the examples
http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#tab4

Assuming the AJAX handler is st as the form target, it's as simple as:

```
$('#myForm1').ajaxForm();
```

You can also override plenty of options as well:

```
// prepare the form when the DOM is ready 
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var options = { 
        target:        '#output1',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
        beforeSubmit:  showRequestFunction,  // pre-submit callback 
        success:       showResponseFunction  // post-submit callback 

        // other available options: 
        //url:       url         // override for form's 'action' attribute 
        //type:      type        // 'get' or 'post', override for form's 'method' attribute 
        //dataType:  null        // 'xml', 'script', or 'json' (expected server response type) 
        //clearForm: true        // clear all form fields after successful submit 
        //resetForm: true        // reset the form after successful submit 

        // $.ajax options can be used here too, for example: 
        //timeout:   3000 
    }; 

    // bind form using 'ajaxForm' 
    $('#myForm1').ajaxForm(options); 
});
```